# pg_dump ignoring table sequence?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have been playing around with PostgreSQL lately, and am having trouble understanding how to backup and restore a single table.

I used pgadmin3 to backup a single table in my database, in order to copy it to a different server.  When I try to do a pg_restore on the file, I get error messages saying that the sequence does not exist:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "businesses_id_seq" does not exist
    Command was: 
CREATE TABLE businesses (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('businesses_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    name character varyin...
```

It looks like the dump file did not include the sequence for my auto incrementing column.  How do I get it to include that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

dumping by table only - will dump only the table. You need to dump the sequence separately in addition to the table.

If you dont know your sequence you can list it with `\d yourtable` in psql. You will see something in the row your sequence is on that looks like : `nextval('yourtable_id_seq'::regclass')`

Then from the command line, `pgdump -t yourtable_id_seq`

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: Do you know if I can specify a comma after th -t flag?  Like this: pgdump -t mytable, mytabl_id_seq

Comment: No, but you can specify multiple -t switches.   Like this: 

    pgdump -t mytable -t mytabl_id_seq