# Hibernate: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, constraints

I am trying to insert into a new record to my postgresql using Hibernate and Java EE.

This is my model:

```
@Entity
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class BaseDesign implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Expose
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private int version;

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    // getter and setter
}
```

And here is my import.sql

```
INSERT INTO basedesign (id, name, version) VALUES (1, 'China', 0);
```

When I build the code, the record is added into db.

However, when I try to add a new record using EntityManager, like this:

```
BaseDesign design = new BaseDesign();
design.setName("USA");                  
em.persist(design);
```

I got:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "basedesign_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

Execute the same command for second time, and it success.

Why do Hibernate not increment the starting ID at the first time? And how to configure it to start at the last inserted integer?

Answer (score 21):

When you create a `bigserial` column in Postgresql, you [are actually creating a sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL).  When you manually inserted an ID value of '1', Postgresql did not update the sequence to take this into account. Hibernate lets Postgresql use the sequence to generate the ID, but the first value produced is '1', which clashes. The second value is fine.

If you created the problem by going behind Hibernate and using SQL directly, you should fix it the same way: [use `ALTER SEQUENCE` to set the next value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html):

```
alter sequence basedesign_id_seq restart with 2;
```

Comment: So this solution must assign a known number to it? It can't automatically pick up the last id?

Comment: The problem is your SQL insert statement which manually inserted an ID. The system can automatically pick up IDs, provided that you *always* let the system generate the ID and never provide a value for the id column.

Comment: Thanks. What I am trying to achieve, is a backup and restore. When I generate a dump file from DB, it comes with INSERT statement with ID in it. Since that ID is not generated by DB, it caused the above problem.

Comment: Postgresql backup and restore should also backup the sequences. Are you dumping individual tables and not including the sequence? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4611199/184998

Comment: Thanks @AdrianCox This answer kept me from signing myself into a mental asylum :) I was importing data from Excel spreadsheets and could not get rid of the pkey violation.

Answer (score 3):

With **pgAdmin4** I you can change the incrementor to start with 2 (or more) as followings
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please see my answer here [How to avoid id conflicts (uniqueconstraint violation) when using PanacheEntity together with Quarkus "import.sql"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66719558/how-to-avoid-id-conflicts-uniqueconstraint-violation-when-using-panacheentity/)

In a nutshell you can do the following:

```
INSERT INTO ticket(id, name,seat) VALUES (nextval('hibernate_sequence'), 'Phantom of the Opera','11A')
```

Comment: you get an upvote in both places for this - totally saved me.

Answer (score 1):

As @Pipo and @Adrian Cox suggested sequence needs to be manually edited so there 
are no collisions with primary keys.

I used `alter sequence tableName_table_id_seq restart with 2;` command AT THE END of SQL script to avoid this error you posted for getting

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint

For instance, I used it like this (for my project) in SQL script for filling values when starting my application:

```
INSERT INTO author(author_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES(9, 'Dan', 'Brown');
INSERT INTO book(book_id, amount, is_deleted, title, price) VALUES(17, 140, false, 'Hamlet', 22.61);
-- other inserts
-- ...
alter sequence author_author_id_seq restart with 10;
alter sequence book_book_id_seq restart with 18;
```