# How to avoid id conflicts (uniqueconstraint violation) when using PanacheEntity together with Quarkus "import.sql"

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I am using quarkus "import.sql" to add initial data to my application.
This data is accessed by classes extending PanacheEntity.

When inserting new data via rest webservice (with id == null) the first inserts run into this error:

```
FEHLER: doppelter Schlüsselwert verletzt Unique-Constraint »task_pkey«
  Detail: Schlüssel »(id)=(1)« existiert bereits.
```

How can I tell panache to start using Ids starting above the data inserted by import.sql?

Comment: For now I am using negative Ids in the import.sql to avoid conflicts

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nextval('hibernate_sequence')` as in:

```
INSERT INTO ticket(id, name,seat) VALUES (nextval('hibernate_sequence'), 'Phantom of the Opera','11A')
```

It will increment the DB sequence when inserting rows.

Source: http://www.mastertheboss.com/soa-cloud/quarkus/managing-data-persistence-with-quarkus/

Answer (score 0):

For Hibernate ORM 6, expected sequence is `<entity-name>_seq`, for example:

`INSERT INTO ticket(id, name,seat) VALUES (nextval('ticket_seq'), 'Phantom of the Opera','11A')`

Also note that ids generated via sequence increment by 50.

Source: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.0/migration-guide.adoc#implicit-identifier-sequence-and-table-name